# Get member of parent struct

Tags: c++, qt, class, struct

I've created an SSCE to better explain this.

In a class, I have a variable, a struct, and a declaration of the struct. Within that struct is a constructor, a variable, a struct and a declaration of that struct. And inside THAT struct is a constructor.

So is goes `Mother > Daughter > GDaughter` aka `class > struct > struct`

mother.h

```
#ifndef MOTHER_H
#define MOTHER_H

#include <QSplitter>

class Mother : public QSplitter
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Mother(int);
    int age;

    struct Daughter
    {
        Daughter();
        int height1;

        struct GDaughter
        {
            GDaughter();
        };
        GDaughter *kate;
    };
    Daughter *tina;
};

#endif // MOTHER_H
```

Now let's take a look at the constructors/source. Here lies my issue.

mother.cpp

```
#include "mother.h"
#include <QDebug>

Mother::Mother(int a)
{
    age = a;
    tina = new Daughter();
}

Mother::Daughter::Daughter()
{
    qDebug() << age;   //Not going to work... I get it. Daughter isnt a derived class

    height1 = 10;
    kate = new GDaughter();
}

Mother::Daughter::GDaughter::GDaughter()
{
    qDebug() << height1;   //Why not? The GDaughter instance is a member of Daughter!
}
```

Both `qDebug()` lines throw `is not a type name, static, or enumerator`.

The goal is to create "child" structs dynamically. So a parent struct might have 0 child structs, 1 child struct, or even 100 child structs. That is why I am using structs instead of derived classes. This setup looks like it would work except for the problem where "parent" variables can't be accessed.

I will include the other files anyway:

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "mother.h"
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    mom = new Mother(50);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "mother.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    Mother *mom;

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

If I am misunderstanding how to go about making something like this then let me know.

Thanks for your time.

---

AFTER ANSWER

In the mother.h I added parent pointers:

```
struct Daughter
{
    Daughter(Mother *p); //Here
    int height1;
    struct GDaughter
    {
        GDaughter(Daughter *p); //And here
    };
    GDaughter *kate;
};
```

and in mother.cpp I filled in the needed code:

```
Mother::Mother(int a)
{
    age = a;
    tina = new Daughter(this); //Here
}

Mother::Daughter::Daughter(Mother *m) //Here
{
    qDebug() << m->age; //Here

    height1 = 10;
    kate = new GDaughter(this); //Here
}

Mother::Daughter::GDaughter::GDaughter(Daughter *d) //Here
{
    qDebug() << d->height1; //Here
}
```

Comment: Your design is confusing. Is `age` the age of the mother or the daughter? It would be way better if you just used functions and private member variables to pass the values to other classes. There also seems to be no reason to use nested structures.

Comment: I'm aware, this is an SSCE to test different things. This is not my actual program. mother, daughter, and gdaughter are just simpler ways to see the nesting... it doesn't matter...

Comment: I see. I was thrown off by the names you chose for this particular example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep pointer(std::weak_ptr if you use smart pointers, for example) to parent class object in nested object.

```
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
```

look at Qt code here, you pass pointer to the parent object in constructor,
if parent is nullptr that means MainWindow has no parent object, Also you can keep
pointer to MainWindow parent object and then static_cast it to exact class

```
     #include <iostream>
    class A {
        class B{
        public:
            B(A *p):parent(p) { parent->hello(); }
        private:
            A *parent;
        };

    public:
        A() { b = new B(this); }

       void hello() { std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl; }
    private:
       B *b;
    };
```

Comment: Hello, I'm afraid I don't understand your answer. Can you expand on that or reword it?

Comment: It worked. Thanks so much! I'll update my answer with exact changes in a sec. Quick question though, how could GDaughter access the class (Mother) variable age? Because my actual program has more than 1 nest. It has around 5. Is there an elegant way of doing this? Basically going higher up the nest than just 1 parent. Would I just create a bunch of getter functions?

Comment: Add public method parent() which will return object's parent object, then call it obj->Parent()->Parent()->Parent()->age();  Glad I could help :)

Comment: Thanks so so much! :)

Comment: also dont forget to delete child object in destructor, also good practice to use smart pointers - base class keep child objects in std::shared_ptr and children keep weak_ptr to base class(so u wont have situation when 2 objects keep shared_ptr reference to each other and cannot be deleted).

Comment: I'll look into that. Thanks